# Foundation block-grid not spacing correctly

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I was told the block-grid would space items evenly within the grid. Do I need to add a ".last" or something to the last li element for it to space them evenly? Because this is not evenly spaced, https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXeCE.png. You can see down below which border belongs to which element.

This is the only HTML in the body section. Using the latest version.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 column" style="border: 1px solid red;">
        <ul class="large-block-grid-4" style="border: 1px solid black;">
            <li><img src="http://placehold.it/150" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://placehold.it/150" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://placehold.it/150" /></li>
            <li style="border: 1px solid blue;"><img src="http://placehold.it/150" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

Comment: How big is your monitor? Because this works, you are using a medium sized screen... Let me show you a demo.

Comment: It could also be that you are using a monitor that is beyond the normal dimensions of a large screen, which means that there will always be a slight difference. Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sbt75/451/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `text-align:center;` to your main row and be sure you also include the ability for responsiveness by including grid dimensions for medium/small/extra-small devices. Zurb/Bootstrap are built for responsive devices, meaning it should be easy to create a responsive website. View the JSFiddle below to get a better idea of what I am talking about.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Sbt75/451/)**

Comment: On a laptop right now which is 1366x768. Was hoping I didn't need to use text-align since it doesn't align with the content that is under/above. But I guess it's either that or use columns to align it.